# How to build dart library libserialport for MacOS?

Tags: macos, dart, dart-ffi

How do you bundle and/or deploy the dart library libserialport in MacOS?

The readme makes mention of the need to bundle and/or deploy if one is to use this library in their dart code (as opposed to flutter).

What I figured out is that I need to make a .dylib which I believe is done from the C code. I have searched in the folder where libserial was installed (directory shown below) but do not see any C code to make a .dylib:

Directory: `/Users/myaccount/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/libserialport-0.3.0+1`

Is anyone familiar with what to do and open to sharing?

Thank you!

Comment: If this is for a project that you plan to use yourself, you can just install libserialport itself onto your computer from the [website](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport).

Comment: The companion project `flutter_libserialport` includes the C source code and should build it for you as part of the overall Flutter build process.

Comment: Though, with that said, the macos build seems to rely on it already being installed (which may be automated by the podspec)